# How Should I Build a has_one through Association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-one-through

For a `has_one` association I can build an association like this:

```
foo.build_bar()
```

**How should I build a `has_one, through:` association?**

For example:

```
class Foo

  has_one :bar
  has_one :baz, through: :bar

end
```

How should I build `baz`? In this example `foo.build_baz` gets me a `No Method Error`.

Documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) says:

> When you declare a has_one association, the declaring class
>   automatically gains four methods related to the association:

```
association(force_reload = false)
association=(associate)
build_association(attributes = {})
create_association(attributes = {})
```

However this doesn't seem to be the case. Using Pry to introspect an instance of `Foo` I can see no such method is added as it would be on a `has_one` without a `through:`.

Comment: Is `has_one: :bar` the `:` after has_one a typo?

Comment: what is relation between bar and baz?

Answer (score 6):

Seems that one possibility is to do:

```
foo.build_bar().build_baz()
foo.save!
```

Comment: This indeed works. I found your argument in the question more convincing. IOW, shouldn't this be considered as one bug in rails, for `has_one` doesn't generate these methods when `through` is used?

Comment: If you don't want to violate the Law of Demeter then you could delegate `build_baz` to `bar`: `delegate :build_baz, to: :bar`